# How to Connect MS ACCESS to Android Apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jdbc, odbc

thanks before i have a problem with my project, my project are make apps in android then the Apps can connect to database in my company but this isn't connect

This is my script

```
 package mas.ganteng;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Mas Ganteng Indonesia
 */
     public class ConnectedAccessActivity {
 Connection conn;
 String url="jdbc:odbc:JavaMsAccess";
 String user="";
 String pass="";
 public Connection getConnection(){
 try {
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
 System.out.println("Connected!!!");
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(ConnectedAccessActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(ConnectedAccessActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
 return conn;
 }
 public static void main(String [] args){
 ConnectedAccessActivity acc=new ConnectedAccessActivity();
 acc.getConnection();
 }

}
```

and it's the console in eclipse

```
    Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:124), pid=3848, tid=3876
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version:  (8.0-b104) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.0-b46 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\My Android\ConnectedAccess\hs_err_pid3848.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Can you help me about this bug?????

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

You're trying to run an Android app as a regular Java program. Run Android apps on an Android emulator or an actual device.

The code looks like it's just a regular Java program. You should remove the Android libraries from it to be able to run it as Java.